# Where can I find the reference format for crypto-config.yaml and configtx.yaml Hyperledger Fabric files?

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Where can I find the reference documentation for the sections of [Hyperledger](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) config files `crypto-config.yaml` and `configtx.yaml`?

The [provided commented sample files](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples) do not explain some sections in details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [sample config files](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/tree/release-1.1/sampleconfig) in the Hyperledger Fabric main code base are fully commented/documented with all sections (though some are commented out).